# Scala vs Haskell typeclasses: "catchall" instances

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass, implicit, scala-implicits

The following Haskell type class and instance:

```
class Able a where
  able :: a -> Int

instance Able Int where
  able x = x
```

is commonly translated to Scala like so:

```
trait Able[A] {
  def able(a: A): Int
}

implicit object AbleInt extends Able[Int] {
  def able(a: Int) = a
}
```

In Haskell I can now define a sort of catch-all instance and thereby create an instance for all Maybe types:

```
instance Able a => Able (Maybe a) where
  able (Just a) = able a
  able Nothing  = 0
```

This defines an instance of `Able` for `Maybe Int`, `Maybe Bool`, etc. provided that there is an instance `Able` for `Int`, `Bool`, etc.

How would one do that in Scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would construct the instance from an implicit parameter for the instance of the peer type `A`. For example:

```
implicit def AbleOption[A](implicit peer: Able[A]) = new Able[Option[A]] {
  def able(a: Option[A]) = a match {
    case Some(x) => peer.able(x)
    case None    => 0
  }
}

assert(implicitly[Able[Option[Int]]].able(None)    == 0)
assert(implicitly[Able[Option[Int]]].able(Some(3)) == 3)
```

Comment: Ingenious! Thank you very much :)